# JQuery vTicker plugin not manipulating my list

Tags: javascript, jquery, vticker

I'm having trouble getting [this version of the vTicker plugin](http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/) to work for me, even though the instructions were absurdly simple.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I installed the JQuery vTicker plugin, loaded JQuery 1.7.2 and created the necessary element whose ID the plugin can grab, but my outputted elements aren't being manipulated by the JQuery.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/GhWkT/1/), where my html is as follows.

```
<div id="ticker">
  <ul>
    <li>One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish.</li>
    <li>Four fish, five fish, jump fish, dive fish.</li>
    <li>Six fish, seven fish... what? Eleven fish?</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#ticker').vTicker();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works - check your code to see what is different:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://richhollis.github.com/vticker/downloads/jquery.vticker.js?v=1.13"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="ticker">
    <ul>
    <li>One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish.</li>
    <li>Four fish, five fish, jump fish, dive fish.</li>
    <li>Six fish, seven fish... what? Eleven fish?</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#ticker').vTicker();
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/GhWkT/2/ by switching the JQuery to "No Wrap - in <head>" instead of onLoad. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks for the JQuery in the <head>, so wrapping it in an onLoad window event doesn't work.

Comment: It's to do with how the page is loaded/evaluated. If you want to use onLoad then move the $('#ticker').vTicker(); line into the same block as the plugin code - http://jsfiddle.net/GhWkT/5/